# HRESULT: 0x80131515 on Release

Tags: c#, dll, hresult

We use a third party Dll, called EASendMail40.dll, the thing is that when I build the solution on debug mode everything goes perfect, but when release mode it throws 2 errors Hresult: 0x80131515 for two of the projects.

I've being looking for an answer and anything works.

Things I've already tried:

- Unlock File (file was never locked)
- Copy the file locally
- Un-reference and reference again to both of the projects.
- Add the "LoadFromRemoteSources" tag on the .config.

Additional info:

The error shows an incorrect path to the file, but the .CSProj is correct.

I use the same DLL on another project in the same solution and I have no problems with it.

The solution builds perfect on a workstation, debug and release mode, the problem is when building on the server.

Comment: does the library have the 'Copy to output directory' set on "Copy Always"?

Comment: Yes, it is! Just checked. I think I just solve it, I changed the "Generate serialization assembly from "Auto" to "Off" and errors disappear! Whats the function of this option?

Comment: It is the error code for a NotSupportedException, that doesn't exactly narrow it down.  It is pretty common to take shortcuts when setting up a build server, usually to avoid paying for a VS license.  Penny wise, three pounds of flesh foolish.  When you don't tell us anything about it then you can only get four pounds of guesses.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the project was building fine in debug mode, but I couldnt make it build in release mode.

Since the project was a clean clone from git and on my second computer worked well, I knew it was something in local setup.
It turs out that I had it cloned on **OneDrive**.
Cloning it to normal local path fixed the issue for me.

So be sure to have it local and not on cloud.